# How to get UITableView Label Text string - Custom Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, uitableview

I have a UITableView with CustomCell. The custom cells contain a UILabel and a UIImageView.

I saw online that it is possible to get the text from a normal UITableView cell and store it in a string when the user presses the cell.

But how can you do this when you are using a custom cell? Becuase the name of my UILabel is "type_label" and it has been defined in the header file of my CustomCell XIB.

So in Xcode I can't use:

```
cell.type_label.text"
```

In the following function:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: Try :
`YourCustomCellClass *cell = (YourCustomCellClass *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the tableViewDidSelectRow all you need to do is:

```
UITableViewCellCustomClass *customCell = (UITableViewVellCustomClass*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *labelText = [[customCell type_label] text];
```

That should get you want you need.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code - You have create type_label label's IBOutlet in CCustomCellClass

(file-->new-->subclass--> UITableViewCell-->name it like CustomCellClass) 

Then implement below code

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

static BOOL nibsRegistered = NO;

if (!nibsRegistered) {

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCellClass" bundle:nil];
    [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

CustomCellClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[CustomCellClass alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.type_label.text = @"Rocky"; // setting custom cell label

return  cell;

}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @CW0007007 By implementing above code cell.type_label.text is possibel or in my case cell.nameLabel.text.... In my project i have already implemented lot of times....

Comment: Doesn't show how he can access this in didSelectRow. You are only showing him how he can set the text of the customCell label, not what he was asking.. Also, you have a static BOOL set to NO, then you are checking if it is NO. It's always going to be NO ... that's redundant.